# How to use result of search in Smartsheet Python SDK?

Tags: python, json, search, smartsheet-api

After starting the program

```
results = smart.Search.search("2244113312180")
print(results)
```

Getting the data

```
{"results": 
[{"contextData": ["2244113312180"], 
"objectId": 778251154810756, 
"objectType": "row", 
"parentObjectId": 3648397300262788,
 "parentObjectName": "Sample Sheet", 
"parentObjectType": "sheet", 
"text": "2244113312180"}, 
{"contextData": ["2244113312180"],
 "objectId": 7803446734415748, 
"objectType": "row", 
"parentObjectId": 3648397300262788, 
"parentObjectName": "Sample Sheet", 
"parentObjectType": "sheet",
"text": "2244113312180"}], 
"totalCount": 2}
```

How do I use them correctly in my program?
Please provide a correct usage example.

And how to find out the id_column in which the value was found "2244113312180"?

```
new_row = smartsheet.models.Row()

new_row.id = results.objectId
```

Sorry I didn't write the error right away. I can't use the properties from the results. String:

```
new_row.id = results.objectId
```

Causes an error

```
AttributeError: 'SearchResult' object has no attribute 'objectId'
```

Thank you for any help!

P.S. I found how to do it.

```
results = smart.Search.search("2244113312180")
text = str(results)
json_op = json.loads(text)
for i in json_op["results"]:
    new_row = smartsheet.models.Row()
    new_row.id = i["objectId"]
```

I don't know if this is a good solution or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how the second code sample you've included (which updates a cell within a row of a sheet) is relevant to the questions you've asked. For clarity, I'd suggest either removing that code from your post (if it's irrelevant) or add additional info to your post to clarify how this code sample is relevant to the help you're seeking.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me what you mean by *"I tried to insert in-place comments, but it's not correct."*. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I edited the post. Now I hope it became more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SearchResultItem Object](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#searchresultitem-object) definition in the Smartsheet API docs, a search result item will never contain information about the column where a value exists. As the result JSON you've posted shows, if the specified value is found within the row of a sheet (i.e., in any of the cells that row contains), the corresponding search result item will identify the sheet ID (`parentObjectId`) and the row ID (`objectId`).

You can then use those two values to retrieve the row, as described in the [Get Row](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-row) section of the docs:

```
row = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_row(
  4583173393803140,       # sheet_id 
  2361756178769796       # row_id 
)
```

Then you can iterate through the `row.cells` array, checking the `value` property of each cell to determine if it matches the value you searched for previously. When you find a `cell` object that contains that value, the `column_id` property of that `cell` object will give you the column ID where the matching value exists.

****UPDATE:****

Thanks for clarifying info in your original post. I'm updating this answer to provide a complete code sample that implements the approach I described previously. Hope this is helpful!

This code sample does the following:

- searches everything in Smartsheet (that the holder of the API token being used has access to) for a string value
- iterates through search result items to process any "row" results (i.e., anywhere that the string appears within the cells of a sheet)
- replaces any occurrences within (the cells of) a sheet with the string `new value`

```
# set search criteria
query = '2244113312180'

# search everything 
search_results = smart.Search.search(query)

# loop through results 
# (acting upon only search results that appear within a row of a sheet)
for item in search_results.results:
    if item.object_type == 'row':
        # get row
        row = smart.Sheets.get_row(
            item.parent_object_id,       # sheet_id 
            item.object_id               # row_id
        )

        # find the cell that contains the value and update that cell value 
        for cell in row.cells:
            if cell.value == query:
                # build new cell value
                new_cell = smartsheet.models.Cell()
                new_cell.column_id = cell.column_id
                new_cell.value = "new value"
                new_cell.strict = False

                # build the row to update
                new_row = smartsheet.models.Row()
                new_row.id = item.object_id
                new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

                # update row
                result = smart.Sheets.update_rows(
                    item.parent_object_id,      # sheet_id
                    [new_row])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help.